# mathml using ajax on chrome

Tags: php, ajax, mathjax, mathml

I am developing an online test engine. In this project I load questions using AJAX. Some questions contain mathematical equations in the form of MathML.

I am using MathJax for rendering the equations.

In FireFox, everything is working fine. In Chrome if the first question contains MathML it renders perfectly but if the question is loaded using AJAX it does not render.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mathjax not working in Ajax based web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151318/mathjax-not-working-in-ajax-based-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```

This will cause MathJax to typeset the page when it is next able to do so. It guarantees that the typesetting will synchronize properly with the loading of jax, extensions, fonts, stylesheets, and other asynchronous activity, and is the only truly safe way to ask MathJax to process additional material.

[for more information, check MathJax docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html)