# Using Mathjax in ajax call

Tags: ajax, mathjax

A question related to [Mathjax not working in Ajax based web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151318/mathjax-not-working-in-ajax-based-web-page/65710141#65710141)

Maybe a stupid question, but where do I have to add this?

I've added

```
<script>MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);</script>
```

to the page I load with Ajax, but the MathJax is still not loading.

On the main page I've added the script below, and it is working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to typeset the `MathJax` after the page has loaded already, you should call the `MathJax.typeset()` function or the `MathJax.typesetPromise()` if you want to use promises. Make sure you call the above function only after the AJAX has loaded into your page.

See the [docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html) for rendering dynamic content for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: It's worth noting that the question refers to the MathJax v2 API while using MathJax v3 (and thus needs the new API as described in this answer).

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger If I understand you correct, I have to change the way I use MathJax in my main page?

Comment: @user2051376 Using MathJax v3 (as in the script src in your question), in the other script,  replace MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]); with MathJax.typesetPromise().

Comment: See also http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/upgrading/v2.html#v2-api-changes